# How can I add a unique ID to each link of a certain class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing something where I find a list of links and generate a save button. I want to prevent the save button from showing on links that are already saved, though, so I plan on giving each of the links a unique ID based on a unique number in the URL of the main links and just disabling it if it's already been saved. I'm not quite sure how I can accomplish this, though.

This is currently what I have:

```
    $(".fl a").after(' <a href="#" class="appended">Save</a>');
    $(".appended").attr('id', $(this).prev().attr("href").split("=")[1]);
```

There will always be a link that matches that split pattern immediately before a link of the appended class. What is the correct way to achieve this? Apparently I can't use $(this) in this context but I don't know what to do instead.

Comment: Where do you save this? Can't you do this on the server side?

Comment: You could use `data()` and just create a "saved" variable so you know it's been used.

Comment: It's a chrome extension so I'm saving it in chrome storage. I have the ID saving working fine, it's just a matter of determining which links don't need to have the save option. I guess I could skip adding the ID to the link and just read the URLs directly and do it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.each()`:

```
$(".appended").each(function() {
    this.id = $(this).prev().attr("href").split("=")[1];
});
```

This will iterate over elements with class `appended` and change the ID accordingly.

Comment: probably you can also write `$(".appended").attr('id', function(){return $(this).prev().attr("href").split("=")[1]});`

Comment: @PSL Why is that better than the suggested answer?  Looks more long-winded to me, but achieves exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Archer I dint say it is better or worse. I just said you can also write... :)

Comment: It does work, thank you. I'm still trying to get the hang of the jquery api so simple stuff like this goes under the radar sometimes..

Comment: @PSL -- I like the suggestion, it's always good to know the different approaches one can take.

Comment: @ssb -- No worries on that, practice makes perfect :).

Comment: what would be better is to use: `this.id = ...`

Comment: +1 and you keep $(this).attr('href') which is not the same as this.href  good point  ;)